# truffle-contract Contract.new() produce an empty contract(no state)

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, truffle-contract

I am making a new copy of a already deployed contract.
I am using truffle, truffle-contract to do so.
From JS front end

```
var conf = contract(MyContract)
    conf.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider)
    conf.new(this.state.party1name, this.state.party1regaddress, this.state.party2address, this.state.effdate,
            {from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas : 3000000})
    .then((instance) => {conf = instance
        console.log(conf.address)
        console.log(conf.get())
    })
```

The above code deploys a new contract for me, but it seems like ignoring all the parameters I give and the state of my new contract is empty.

When i do the same thing from truffle console, it works fine

```
MyContract.new("Manish", "Raffles Place", "0x61b755c693d7cf263f969f336be281a564af915d", {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]})
```

I checked in console I get below log

[image]

So I am getting the new contract address but values passed into my constructor are empty.

Comment: I checked in console regarding my calls, I can see promise.value

Comment: I can't say much but I'd check the parameters to new are, just a console.log to ensure the values are correct. Other problem I've is that truffle artifacts will get out of sync, so I've to delete `build/` folder to force a contracts recompilation.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael.. that helped..I just deleted all compiled abi in build folder and compiled and deployed all of them again and made my constructor payable and guess what...its working smoothly now

Comment: You may add that as an answer so it can help others in similar situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted all compiled abi in build folder and compiled and deployed all of them again and made my constructor payable and guess what...its working smoothly now